# Does this multiplicative function have a name? If so, what is known about it?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

It is well-known that the Euler $\phi$-function is multiplicative: that is, for co-prime positive integers $m,n$ we have $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)$. Thus it is defined by its values on prime powers. We know that $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1} (p-1)$ for all primes $p$.

What about the multiplicative function $\psi$ defined on the primes by $\psi(p^k) = p^{k-1} (p+1)$? Does it have a name? If so, what's known about it?

For example, can one evaluate $\sum_{n \leq X} \psi(n)$?

Comment: I found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cpsi(p%5Ek)%20%3D%20p%5E%7Bk-1%7D%20(p%2B1)%24&p=1) that this function is mentioned in this post: [Mean Value of a Multiplicative Function close to $n$ in Terms of the Zeta Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/90120). The topic of that post is exactly deriving some kind of asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n \leq X} \psi(n)$.

Comment: $\psi(n) = \# \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is the number of points on the projective line.

Comment: I am not sure to which extent this is interesting, but here is another context in which this function appears: [How can we show the equality $[SL_2(\mathbb Z): \Gamma_0(N)]=N\prod_{p\mid N}\left(1+\frac1p\right)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1733267). (As you can probably guess, I found the question using Approach0.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\psi$ is the multiplicative convolution of $\mu^2$ and the identity function, hence its Dirichlet series is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(2s)},\qquad\Re(s)>2.$$ 
This implies by [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula) and standard bounds that 
$$\sum_{n \leq X} \psi(n)\sim\frac{\zeta(2)}{2\zeta(4)}X^2=\frac{15}{2\pi^2}X^2.$$

Comment: I will just add this function appears in [Exercise 11 in Chapter 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=3yoBCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71) in Apostol's book. [The last part](https://books.google.com/books?id=3yoBCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA72) of this exercise is the asymptotic formula
$\sum_{n\le x} \varphi_1(n)=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2\zeta(4)}x^2+O(x\log x)$. (Apostol denotes the function by $\varphi_1$.)

Comment: In the field of automorphic forms, this function is often denotes $\nu(n)$ (for example, in Iwaniec-Luo-Sarnak's seminal paper on low-lying zeroes of $L$-functions of holomorphic cuspidal eigenforms).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks for your comment. Clearly, one can also prove this statement by elementary means, by making use of the convolution I mentioned.

Comment: @PeterHumphries: Indeed the function looked familiar! It is also the index of $\Gamma_0(n)$ in $\Gamma_0(1)$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @GHfromMO, yep, which is why it comes up in the field automorphic forms so often!

Answer (score 8):

This is also called the [Dedekind $\psi$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function):
$$
\psi(n):=n\prod_{p|n}(1+p^{-1})
$$

See also [A001615](https://oeis.org/A001615) and [A158523](https://oeis.org/A158523).

Comment: This should be a comment in my opinion, but thanks for it anyways. (Usually answers should be true answers, which really answer the original question.)

Comment: @GHfromMO You obviously know more about the etiquette of this site than me, but I do believe I answered the main two questions in the OP: "does this have a name", and "what is known about it". I didn't say anything about the asymptotics, because that was already covered by you, and because that seemed to me as an example question, and not the main one. But I appreciate the feedback anyway.

Comment: I agree with you. I forgot about those parts of the question! (BTW it is usually discouraged to ask several questions in one post, exactly to avoid confusions like this.)

Comment: I find it amazing that I used the same letter as the generally accepted one!